# How to get driver for z location by name (without looping)

Tags: python, drivers

I wish to be able to reference the driver for Location Z by name. Whenever I try using somethings like

```
object.animation_data.drivers[object.location.z]
```

or

```
object.animation_data.drivers[object.location[2]]
```

I get

```
TypeError:bpy_prop_collection[key]: invalid key, must be a string or an int, not Float
```

Any object I will call this function on will have a driver for Z location. Instead of iterating through the collection I was hoping I can call it by name (like properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find in the API documentation that there is a built in function for this collection.

Calling

```
object.animation_data.drivers.find('location',2)
```

did the trick.

Comment: If this _"did the trick"_, accept your answer to avoid  community bot bump.

Comment: My apologies. I have accepted the answer. Thanks